# Passing arguments java8

Tags: java, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a method doStuff(String arg1).
I invoke it from the object someObject, passing it the "constant name" as the String argument.
Can I get the value of this variable inside the doStuff method?

```
public Class1 {
     someObject.doStuff("SOME_CONST");
}


public Class2 {
     public static final String SOME_CONST = "someString";

     public void doStuff(String arg1) {
          doMoreStuff(arg1); 
     }

     // expected: doMoreStuff("someString"), but actual:  
     doMoreStuff("SOME_CONST").
}
```

Comment: `someObject.doStuff(Class2.SOME_CONST);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure what you're asking but you can get the value by reflection, like this. (It will print CONSTANT)

```
public static class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class2().doStuff("SOME_CONST");
    }
}

public static class Class2 {
    public static final String SOME_CONST = "CONSTANT";

    public void doStuff(String const_name) {
        try {
            String const_value = (String) Class2.class.getDeclaredField(const_name).get(null);
            System.out.println(const_value);
        }catch(NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this : `someObject.doStuff(Class2.SOME_CONST);` instead of `someObject.doStuff("SOME_CONST");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the attribute : `SOME_CONST`

```
public static final String SOME_CONST = "someString";
```

As a parameter for :    `doMoreStuff(...)`
You need to write this : `doMoreStuff(SOME_CONST);`

Because `doMoreStuff("SOME_COST");` will pass as parameter the `String "SOME_COST"` and not the variable